# "streaming" messages to a broker from a batch-like source (eg sql database), optionally acknowledge back to the source

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I am writing library code to help other developers send messages to a pub-sub event broker.

In many cases, the message source will not be "stream-like". Specifically, most messages are coming from SQL Server change data capture, and are therefore much more efficiently read in sets (batches).

Additionally, in most cases the message should be "guaranteed" - ie, if we fail to send the message to the broker then we should send it again, even if the sending application crashes for some reason. This implies letting the source know that a message has been sent. As was the case with reading from the source, acknowledging back to it is also set based, for the same reason.

It is acceptable that a message may be "accidentally" sent multiple times in exception-like circumstances, (guaranteed-once-in-order delivery is much too hard a problem for me to solve in my little implementation here!), but this should not occur if everything is running smoothly.

Batch sizes might be large, so I don't really want to concurrently execute `n` publish-to-broker tasks, where `n` is the number of messages in the batch, because that could potentially be a heck of a lot of `Task` objects being waited on by something like `Task.WhenAll`. Therefore I have used `DataFlow` as a concurrency-limiting mechanism.

Here are the Interfaces I have created (I am fairly happy with these so skip over them if you don't need the context, although I do wonder if the `AcknowledgeAsync` method should accept an `IAsyncEnumerable` for symmetry). The `IGuaranteedBatchProvider` does not extend `IBatchProvider`, because acknowledgement only requires an `IMessage`, not an `IMessage<T>`.

```cs
public interface IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows a message to be tracked locally through processing pipeline, either on the
    /// publication or subscription side, but the values sent by a publisher will not be the same
    /// as those received by a subscriber, since the LocalMessageId values for messages received
    /// by susbcribers are generated by the broker
    /// </summary>
    public long LocalMessageId { get; init; }
}

public interface IMessage<T> : IMessage
{
    public T Payload { get; init; }
}

public interface IBatchProvider<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a batch of unacknowledged messages from the source. If the provider is also a
    /// guaranteed provider, then all messages in a batch should be acknowledged prior to reading
    /// a new batch, otherwise the new batch will contain duplicate messages
    /// </summary>
    IAsyncEnumerable<IMessage<T>> ReadBatchAsync(ushort maxBatchSize, CancellationToken ct);
}
 
public interface IGuaranteedBatchProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// informs a guaranteed provider that a set of messages have been successfully transmitted.
    /// Acknowledged messages will not be returned by subsequent read operations
    /// </summary>
    Task AcknowledgeAsync(IEnumerable<IMessage> messagesToAcknowledge, CancellationToken ct);
}

public interface IPublication<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// sends a message to the broker, returns true if the payload is successfully published
    /// </summary>
    Task<bool> PublishAsync(T payload);
}
```

The code I am interested in having reviewed is in my `BatchPublisher` class. This helper class understands how to work with the interfaces described above. The `Run` loop is what follows. I would particularly appreciate feedback for the section of code commented as `//ugly?`, whether a `Channel` implementation might be more appropriate (I have not yet used channels), and of course any overall comments about the overall design. Most exception handling removed for brevity.

The provider here would typically be a `CdcProvider<T> : IBatchProvider<T>, IGuaranteedBatchProvider`

```cs
public async Task Run(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<(IMessage msg, bool result)>();

    // ugly?
    Func<IMessage<T>, Task> publish = provider is IGuaranteedBatchProvider
        ? async (msg) => results.Add((msg, await publication.PublishAsync(msg.Payload)))
        : async (msg) => _ = await publication.PublishAsync(msg.Payload);

    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        results.Clear();

        // channels instead? Newing up the actionblock every batch seems wrong somehow
        ActionBlock<IMessage<T>> limiter = new
        (
            async (msg) =>
            {
                try { await publish(msg); }
               // if the consuming application as registered an event handler for publication
               // exceptions, call it (mostly for error logging)
                catch (Exception x) { PublishFailed?.Invoke(this, (msg, x)); }
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = ct,
                EnsureOrdered = true,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = sendConcurrency
            }
        );

        await foreach (var message in provider.ReadBatchAsync(maxReadBatchSize, ct))
        {
            limiter.Post(message);
        }
        limiter.Complete();
        await limiter.Completion;
        if (!results.IsEmpty && provider is IGuaranteedBatchProvider p)
        {
            await p.AcknowledgeAsync(results.Select(r => r.msg), ct);
        }
    }
}
```